# Pan-sharpening Landsat 8 with 5 bands

Tags: landsat-8, multi-band, pansharpening

I use bands 654 for vegetation classification and bands 432 to prepare the map layout.

Is there a way to pan-sharpen the landsat 8 image using the bands 65432 ? So I swicth the GRB to classify and to Layout.

Comment: @Mikkel, Is there a way to make these process in the Arcgis 10.3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A three step process in QGIS:

1. Stack the Landsat 8 multispectral bands that you require using "Build Virtual Raster".
2. Use "Superimpose sensor" with the panchromatic band as 'reference' and the output from step 1 as 'the image to reproject'.
3. Use "Pansharpening (Bayes)" with the panchromatic band as 'Input PAN Image' and the output from step 2 as 'Input XS Image'

All tools are indicated with " ", while input parameters are marked with ' '.
The tools can be found in the Advanced Interface in the Processing Toolbox.

Comment: @JoseAlfredo note that you may want to use another pansharpening tool than the lmvm-version. I just finished reviewing the different ones, and I have had the best results with "Pansharpening (Bayes)".