# Landsat 8 composite image using different resolutions?

Tags: classification, landsat, resolution, pansharpening, composite

I have created a composite image of Landsat 8 using bands 2 to 7 (blue, green, red, NIR and SWIR) using ArcGIS 10.1. For bands 2-4, I've pansharpened them to 15m spatial resolutions using the panchromatic band, while bands 5-7 are in 30m spatial resolutions.

Will the different spatial resolutions pose a problem when I perform image classification later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Differing resolutions will likely cause issues for you later on. I'd suggest either resampling the 30m bands to 15m using a bilinear interpolation, or even pansharpening those bands as well. ArcGIS will not allow you to pansharpen those bands, but using tools in QGis will let you do it.

Comment: Any specific tools/plugins in QGIS you'd suggest? I've tried the "semi-automatic classification" plugin but it did not resample my bands 5-7 (30m resolution) to 15m along with bands 2-4 (15m resolution); bands 5-7 were included in the composite image but they were filled entirely with null values.

Comment: You can read about how to do it in this post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173732/pan-sharpening-landsat-8-with-5-bands/173744#173744