# Error in GRASS i.pansharpen - No images are generated

Tags: qgis, landsat-8, pansharpening

I´m trying to run the algorithm "i.pansharpen" in QGIS 2.18.8 , Win. 7_64bit.
I´ve tried with rasters (Landsat 8 images) in 8bit and 16 bit unsigned and differents methods (brovey and IHS) but i always get the same error and no file is generated. The process log  written above.
Somebody has an idea what i´m doing wrong?[image]

```
    Algorithm i.pansharpen - Image fusion algorithms to sharpen multispectral with high-res panchromatic channels starting...
g.proj -c proj4="+proj=utm +zone=24 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
r.external input="D:/Documentos/ProjetosEstagio/TESTE_PANCROMATICA/Rodolfo/IHS/8_bit/MOS_4_8bit.tif" band=1 output=tmp1495630956933 --overwrite -o
r.external input="D:/Documentos/ProjetosEstagio/TESTE_PANCROMATICA/Rodolfo/IHS/8_bit/MOS_5_8bit.tif" band=1 output=tmp1495630956934 --overwrite -o
r.external input="D:/Documentos/ProjetosEstagio/TESTE_PANCROMATICA/Rodolfo/IHS/8_bit/MOS_3_8bit.tif" band=1 output=tmp1495630956935 --overwrite -o
r.external input="D:/Documentos/ProjetosEstagio/TESTE_PANCROMATICA/Rodolfo/IHS/8_bit/MOS_8_3_8bit.tif" band=1 output=tmp1495630956936 --overwrite -o
g.region n=7870612.15599 s=7800623.29292 e=357677.622271 w=122481.445768 res=29.9995123091
i.pansharpen red="tmp1495630956933" green="tmp1495630956934" blue="tmp1495630956935" pan="tmp1495630956936" method=ihs -l -s output="tmp1495630956937" --overwrite
r.out.gdal -c -t -f --overwrite createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" input=tmp1495630956937_red output="D:/Documentos/ProjetosEstagio/TESTE_PANCROMATICA/Rodolfo/IHS/R.tif"
r.out.gdal -c -t -f --overwrite createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" input=tmp1495630956937_green output="D:/Documentos/ProjetosEstagio/TESTE_PANCROMATICA/Rodolfo/IHS/G.tif"
r.out.gdal -c -t -f --overwrite createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" input=tmp1495630956937_blue output="D:/Documentos/ProjetosEstagio/TESTE_PANCROMATICA/Rodolfo/IHS/B.tif"

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set HOME=C:\Users\TBE 02-Estagiario 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set GISRC=C:\Users\TBE 02-Estagiario\.qgis2\\processing\processing.gisrc7 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set WINGISBASE=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set GISBASE=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set GRASS_PROJSHARE=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\share\proj 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set GRASS_MESSAGE_FORMAT=plain 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>if "" == "" set PATH=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\shapely\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\qgis\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\WBem 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>if not "" == "" set PATH=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\lib;;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\shapely\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\qgis\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\WBem 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set GRASS_VERSION=7.2.1 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>if not "" == "" goto langset 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %i IN (`"C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\etc\winlocale"`) DO @set LANG=%i 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set PYTHONPATH=;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\etc\python;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\etc\wxpython\n 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="MAPSET=PERMANENT" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="LOCATION=temp_location" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="LOCATION_NAME=temp_location" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="GISDBASE=C:\Users\TBE02-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing12eb90bb6ea14c6e9223aa7fab4aba80\grassdata" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="GRASS_GUI=text" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.proj -c proj4="+proj=utm +zone=24 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" 
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default 
Projection information updated 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.external input="D:/Documentos/ProjetosEstagio/TESTE_PANCROMATICA/Rodolfo/IHS/8_bit/MOS_4_8bit.tif" band=1 output=tmp1495630956933 --overwrite -o 
ATENÇÃO: Se sobrepondo à verificação da projeção 
Reading band 1 of 1... 
r.external completo. Link to raster map created. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.external input="D:/Documentos/ProjetosEstagio/TESTE_PANCROMATICA/Rodolfo/IHS/8_bit/MOS_5_8bit.tif" band=1 output=tmp1495630956934 --overwrite -o 
ATENÇÃO: Se sobrepondo à verificação da projeção 
Reading band 1 of 1... 
r.external completo. Link to raster map created. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.external input="D:/Documentos/ProjetosEstagio/TESTE_PANCROMATICA/Rodolfo/IHS/8_bit/MOS_3_8bit.tif" band=1 output=tmp1495630956935 --overwrite -o 
ATENÇÃO: Se sobrepondo à verificação da projeção 
Reading band 1 of 1... 
r.external completo. Link to raster map created. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.external input="D:/Documentos/ProjetosEstagio/TESTE_PANCROMATICA/Rodolfo/IHS/8_bit/MOS_8_3_8bit.tif" band=1 output=tmp1495630956936 --overwrite -o 
ATENÇÃO: Se sobrepondo à verificação da projeção 
Reading band 1 of 1... 
r.external completo. Link to raster map created. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.region n=7870612.15599 s=7800623.29292 e=357677.622271 w=122481.445768 res=29.9995123091 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>i.pansharpen red="tmp1495630956933" green="tmp1495630956934" blue="tmp1495630956935" pan="tmp1495630956936" method=ihs -l -s output="tmp1495630956937" --overwrite 
'""' nÆo  reconhecido como um comando interno 
ou externo, um programa oper vel ou um arquivo em lotes. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set HOME=C:\Users\TBE 02-Estagiario 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set GISRC=C:\Users\TBE 02-Estagiario\.qgis2\\processing\processing.gisrc7 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set WINGISBASE=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set GISBASE=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set GRASS_PROJSHARE=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\share\proj 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set GRASS_MESSAGE_FORMAT=plain 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>if "" == "" set PATH=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\shapely\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\qgis\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\WBem 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>if not "" == "" set PATH=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\lib;;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\shapely\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\qgis\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\WBem 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set GRASS_VERSION=7.2.1 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>if not "" == "" goto langset 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %i IN (`"C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\etc\winlocale"`) DO @set LANG=%i 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set PYTHONPATH=;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\etc\python;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\etc\wxpython\n 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="MAPSET=PERMANENT" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="LOCATION=temp_location" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="LOCATION_NAME=temp_location" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="GISDBASE=C:\Users\TBE02-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing12eb90bb6ea14c6e9223aa7fab4aba80\grassdata" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="GRASS_GUI=text" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.out.gdal -c -t -f --overwrite createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" input=tmp1495630956937_red output="D:/Documentos/ProjetosEstagio/TESTE_PANCROMATICA/Rodolfo/IHS/R.tif" 
ERRO:Raster map or group not found 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.out.gdal -c -t -f --overwrite createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" input=tmp1495630956937_green output="D:/Documentos/ProjetosEstagio/TESTE_PANCROMATICA/Rodolfo/IHS/G.tif" 
ERRO:Raster map or group not found 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>r.out.gdal -c -t -f --overwrite createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" input=tmp1495630956937_blue output="D:/Documentos/ProjetosEstagio/TESTE_PANCROMATICA/Rodolfo/IHS/B.tif" 
ERRO:Raster map or group not found 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>exit 
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers
Algorithm i.pansharpen - Image fusion algorithms to sharpen multispectral with high-res panchromatic channels finished
```

Comment: While not a answer to your actual question, may I suggest a different approach to your problem: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173732/pan-sharpening-landsat-8-with-5-bands?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen, These approach is the Orpheo Monteverdi algorithm, isn´t it? I´ve obtained success with this method, but I would like to try the IHS or Brovey to evaluate the best technic to my problem (:

Comment: Yes - it is a Orfeo based approach that I suggest. As for why the GRASS tool fails, I don't have the software installed the same way, but try to make sure that the i.pansharpen.bat exists in the C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin directory

Comment: this file only exists in this directory: C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1 . Is the QGIS searching in the wrong directory?

Comment: The important error message is: C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>i.pansharpen red="tmp1495630956933" green="tmp1495630956934" blue="tmp1495630956935" pan="tmp1495630956936" method=ihs -l -s output="tmp1495630956937" --overwrite 
'""' nÆo  reconhecido como um comando interno 
ou externo, um programa oper vel ou um arquivo em lotes.

Comment: Why the error occurs is a good question, and one to which I don't have the answer. In general, I do my best to avoid GRASS GIS, as it seems prone to problems with the setup.